# Using bzr with SFTP on Windows/Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, sftp, bazaar

**Note: I'm not sure if this belongs on ServerFault or StackOverflow**

I'm currently working on a project which has an SFTP-only `bzr` repository. All works fine using my Linux machine, but when using Windows with Cygwin I get the following issue:

```
$ bzr checkout sftp://user@hostname/var/bzr/project
bzr: ERROR: Unsupported protocol for url "sftp://user@hostname/var/bzr/project": Unable to import paramiko (required for sftp support): No module named Crypto
```

I have installed Cygwin's `python-paramiko` package, so I'm not sure why it's refusing to use it.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

*Clarification: This does work with Windows bazaar GUI tool & Windows `cmd` shell, I'm just wondering if I can make it work in Cygwin as I prefer UNIXy command line tools.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played around with this today.

Had to install `python-crypto` which should be a prerequisite of `python-paramiko` but isn't.

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but this page can be useful in your use case: http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/InstallationFaq . Also, I recommend using `pip` to install Python modules, always, regardless of the OS.